# Dynamic model attribute with SAILSJS

Tags: dynamic, model, sails.js

My use case needs me to use Dynamic Model attributes with my Sails.Js project and all of my methods fail. First I tried to call model1 method from model2 but it doesn't works. I also tried to use global variables but this fails too because, the global is set after the load of the application, and finaly I called model1Controller from the model2 but it still not working.
This is the mothod in my model2Controller

```
 getbyTable:function(req,res){
        let field = Field.find({fTable:req.param('tableName')});
        field.exec(function(err, response) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500);
            return res.view('500', {data: err});
        }
        //res.json(response);
        return response;
        });
    },
```

And this is my model2

```
'use strict';
const fieldController = require('../controllers/Model1Controller');

const donnees = fieldController.getbyTable('person');

module.exports={

}
```

When run it fires as error that req.param is not a function.
Need help!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an interesting way to organize - I'd be curious to see how successful a project could be without Model attributes set in stone.

I can see a few specific errors in your code, maybe seeing them will help you move forward.

1. From your model2 you invoke `getbyTable('person')` with a string argument - but all controller methods are really intended to have reqest/response arguments (as in the definition `getbyTable(req, res)`. Directly invoking a controller method is a bit unusual - if you ever did it, I'd expect to pass along a request and response from some other controller method.
2. Inside `getbyTable`, you try to return the response, but the response is only defined inside the `exec` callback. The response would be an array of objects fetched from your database - if that's what you need, you can't return them directly since database calls are async.
3. Your controller should probably do something with `res` in all logical branches, such as `res.json`, `res.send`, etc.

It's a bit hard to see exactly what you're trying to achieve, so maybe if you could explain the goal I could have some more relevant advice. For now, I could say that you might want to consider putting some code inside a service rather than a controller. Create file `/api/services/MyService.js` and use it to export a method that can be called from your model2 (you can require the service just like the controller). Keep the controller methods strictly for handling requests.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going apply changes in you advices. What I am trying to do : I have a Field table that contains all of the table attributes in my database, so that instead of specifying model attribut one by one, I'd like to fetch from Field table all records where tableName = my table name.

Comment: I see - if I understand, you would load your fields from the table for each model when the application "lifts". This could work. I would try creating a `FieldService` and call this in each model to get the fields you need.

Comment: I would not be surprised if using the `Field` model while you are defining your other models caused some sort of problem (maybe `Field` is not defined yet at this point) - you may need to look into getting the underlying database and using it more directly to get your fields - maybe requiring the underlying db driver (ex `require('mongodb')` or something directly.